# Is generating real random numbers this easy in C#?

Tags: c#

I found this code using Google.

```
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
Random random = new Random();
return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

Is this really all there is to generating REAL random numbers in C#? I intend to generate on a small scale between values 1-10.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `REAL` random numbers?  The RNG of C# (and that of most languages is, by design/standard, a _pseudo_ RNG, but by feeding it relatively random seeds (from say the time of day clock), it produces truly novel series, with a [almost] uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make your own class that wraps the already existing "Random" class. You can just call:

```
int myNumber = (new Random()).Next(1, 10);
```

Also, regarding "REAL random numbers"... it's random enough for 99.99% of the needs out there in the world.

Comment: And this is as random as it gets... I remember in classic ASP days, you needed to Jazz it up a bit?

Comment: I know some Random classes in a few languages that returns a number between 0 and 1, but yeah that is all to it.

Comment: Yeah, I used to use the "keyword" RANDOMIZE ... and when I switched from VB to VB.NET then to C#, I was freaking out not knowing where to put the code :)

Comment: I'm not going to vote you down, but I don't think the asker wanted to know about pseudorandom numbers. It seems that he would like to know if there is a way, as there is in most standard libraries, to pull randoms from the OS, which in turn gets them from hardware noise.

Comment: @Timothy Exactly, I mean its not every day a developer has the need to use random in business scenarios, but I'm writing an app to test my main app. Glad you understood my point, thanks :)

Comment: @avpx - See his comments / his sample code for clarification.

Comment: Your sample code has a potentially fatal flaw. If this were placed in a small function that were called repeatedly in a small period of time, it would repeatedly return the same integer because it would keep getting the same seed and returning the first number from the same series. Unless there is a specific reason to do otherwise, it is important to hold onto and use a single Random object, and your answer makes that very easy to overlook.

Comment: @Snarfblam, you're saying that if you call a `new Random().Next` "really fast" it'll return the same random number? That doesn't sound right at all.

Comment: I wouldn't say "99.99%" of all needs.  The modified Knuth implementation used by `Random` is not suitable for statistical simulations, online gaming, cryptography, or many other applications.  Four nines is a lot.  I might say 90% or even 95%, but not more.

Comment: @yar: He actually is correct, because if you use the default constructor of `Random` then it uses the current timestamp as a seed.  Invoking this several times in rapid succession will create new instances of the `Random` class with the exact same seed that will therefore return the exact same number on the first iteration.  In fact, it's usually a design error to be creating `Random` instances on the fly; in most cases you should probably just be using one instance throughout the application.

Comment: @Aaronaught, 95% = 99.99% about 99.99% of the time :) ... as a side point, I've made MMORPGs, using the basic Random class for spawning, random effects, DEF vs STR calcuations and much more... it was perfect.

Comment: The code in the OP has the exact same flaw.  Should should really have some form of `static Random myRand = new Random(); return myRand.next()`

Comment: @Timothy Khouri: When I said "gaming" I actually meant "gambling", sorry for the misunderstanding. :P

Comment: @Aaronnaught, @Snarfblam, ok good point, my error. I remember this (vaguely) from .Net, that's why they provide the `next` method. Perhaps a more idiot-proof design would've been a good idea for .Net. I wonder if the same timestamp and a fresh `Random` always results in the same random on different computers? This would allow you coordinate randoms (or something).

Comment: That's why you can specify your own seed. It can be useful to generate the same series multiple times, or generate the same series each time while you are debugging.

Answer (score 11):

What do you mean by "real"? They're random numbers, of course, though perhaps not *cryptographically secure* random numbers. For the majority of applications, though, `Random.Next` is definitely good enough.

If you want cryptographically secure random numbers, check out the [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) class.

Answer (score 7):

If you are going to use the Random class (which is fine for most things), you don't want to make a new Random Object for each call. I'd recommend making a static member of the containing class:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
private int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
{
    return random.Next(min, max);
}
```

This is because, by default, the Random class uses the system time.

> **MSDN:** However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers. [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(VS.100).aspx)

For a more "real" random number you can use RNGCryptoServiceProvider (which is mentioned by Dean Harding).

Comment: +1 for the point on near-identical seeding from the system clock when creating multiple instances of Random is close succession.