# the name DiceRoll does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

Here is the issue, at the top I have public void DiceRoller which simply gets a random number for me. Under that is `int DiceRoll` which is what I call to get the number. In my `public void CreateInput()` I call upon DiceRoll and it spits that the name doesn't exist in current context. If I copy the code from DiceRoller into CreateInput it works flawless, but I'd like to have it in its own class for other classes within my code.

```
    public void DiceRoller()
    {
        Random RandomNumber = new Random();
        int DiceRoll = RandomNumber.Next(1, 20);
    }

    public void CreateInput()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("  _, __, __,  _, ___ __,    _, _,_  _, __,  _,  _, ___ __, __,");
        Console.WriteLine(" / ` |_) |_  /_\\  |  |_    / ` |_| /_\\ |_) /_\\ / `  |  |_  |_)");
        Console.WriteLine(" \\ , | \\ |   | |  |  |     \\ , | | | | | \\ | | \\ ,  |  |   | \\");
        Console.WriteLine("  ~  ~ ~ ~~~ ~ ~  ~  ~~~    ~  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  ~   ~  ~~~ ~ ~");
        Console.WriteLine("<==============================================================>");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Player Name: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Select Race: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Select Class: ");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Stats: ");
        Console.Write("STR: ");
        Console.Write(DiceRoll);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Why create an entire class to run one line of code?

Answer (score 1):

In your **current** code, the variable `DiceRoll` is defined in the function `DiceRoller()`, **NOT** in the function `CreateInput()`. This is why you get, `The name DiceRoll does not exist in the current context.`

**My suggestion**

Change return type from `void` to `int` in your `DiceRoller()` function, and return an integer.

```
public int DiceRoller()     
{         
    Random randomNumber = new Random();         
    int diceRoll = randomNumber.Next(1, 20);
    return diceRoll;
}
```

Then, call the function `DiceRoller()` inside your `CreateInput()` function to get your random integer as shown below:

```
public void CreateInput()     
{         
    Console.Clear();         
    Console.WriteLine("  _, __, __,  _, ___ __,    _, _,_  _, __,  _,  _, ___ __, __,");         
    Console.WriteLine(" / ` |_) |_  /_\\  |  |_    / ` |_| /_\\ |_) /_\\ / `  |  |_  |_)");          
    Console.WriteLine(" \\ , | \\ |   | |  |  |     \\ , | | | | | \\ | | \\ ,  |  |   | \\");         
    Console.WriteLine("  ~  ~ ~ ~~~ ~ ~  ~  ~~~    ~  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  ~   ~  ~~~ ~ ~");         
    Console.WriteLine("<==============================================================>");     
    Console.WriteLine();         
    Console.WriteLine();         
    Console.Write("Player Name: ");        
    Console.ReadLine();        
    Console.Write("Select Race: ");         
    Console.ReadLine();        
    Console.Write("Select Class: ");         
    Console.ReadLine();         
    Console.WriteLine("Stats: ");         
    Console.Write("STR: ");         
    Console.Write(DiceRoller());         
    Console.ReadLine();     
}
```

**Personal Preference**: I like to define local variables when I am calling accessor functions. In this case, instead of using `Console.WriteLine(DiceRoller())`, I would define a local variable first (`int random = DiceRoller();`), then write it to console (`Console.WriteLine(random);`).

Answer (score 0):

Is your declaration of DiceRoll inside the function DiceRoller()? If it is, then that variable is local to that specific function, and it doesn't exist outside of it.

You probably should be returning DiceRoll from DiceRoller() and passing it to CreateInput().

Answer (score 0):

`DiceRoll` is no variable and it seems it isn't a constant. It's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a value from DiceRoller().

```
public int DiceRoller()
{
     Random RandomNumber = new Random();
     return RandomNumber.Next(1, 20);
}

Console.Write(DiceRoller());
```

Comment: The method `DiceRoller()` is void.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DiceRoller
{
    int DiceRoll = 0;
    Random RandomNumber = new Random();

    public DiceRoller()
    {
       int DiceRoll = RandomNumber.Next(1, 20);
    }

   public int getDiceRoll()
   {
      return DiceRoll;
   }
}
```

inside whatever class CreateInput() have an instance of `DiceRoller` and call the get method

```
class SomeClass
{
     DiceRoller dr;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        DiceRoller dr = new DiceRoller();
    }  

    public void CreateInput()
    {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("  _, __, __,  _, ___ __,    _, _,_  _, __,  _,  _, ___ __, __,");
            Console.WriteLine(" / ` |_) |_  /_\\  |  |_    / ` |_| /_\\ |_) /_\\ / `  |  |_  |_)");
            Console.WriteLine(" \\ , | \\ |   | |  |  |     \\ , | | | | | \\ | | \\ ,  |  |   | \\");
            Console.WriteLine("  ~  ~ ~ ~~~ ~ ~  ~  ~~~    ~  ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  ~   ~  ~~~ ~ ~");
            Console.WriteLine("<==============================================================>");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Player Name: ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Select Race: ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Select Class: ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Stats: ");
            Console.Write("STR: ");
            Console.Write(dr.getDiceRoll());
            Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void DiceRoller() 
{ 
    Random RandomNumber = new Random(); 
    int DiceRoll = RandomNumber.Next(1, 20); 
}
```

What's happening here is that the moment you finish the DiceRoller() method, all of the local variables are popped off of the stack and you lose all corresponding data.  What you need to do is turn the above function into something of the following:

```
public int DiceRoller() 
{
    Random RandomNumber = new Random();
    return RandomNumber.Next(1,20);
}
```

You could also Create a static variable called RandomNumber so that it is only required to create the seed once: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2466989